# Furniture spawn manipulation and money trees

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

You can manipulate which trees will drop furniture when you shake them by planting a certain number of trees in order, guaranteeing that you get furniture from the same two trees every day.

> 1. Cut down all trees on the island (except fruit trees)
> 2. Buy 7 tree saplings from Nook's Cranny
> 3. Plant 5 of them
> 4. Wait until the trees grow
> 5. Once they're fully grown, plant the remaining 2 trees (furniture will drop from these)
> 6. Once they're fully grown, you're done!

[Guide source here](https://gamewith.net/animal-crossing-new-horizons/article/show/18573)

Does planting money trees interfere with this manipulation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Money trees turn into "regular" deciduous trees once they've been shaken for their moneybags. While I don't exactly understand how the guide is manipulating the tree mechanics, it hinges on there being exactly 7 trees.

If you plant a money tree, you have 8 trees, and all bets are off.

Comment: It mentions that fruit trees are OK. Aren't money trees "fruit" trees until you take their money?

Comment: Right -- at which point they're not. So the day after you harvest them, you've got 8 trees.